# "Exception:Package not found " when running Python Azure function with docx module in VS Code

Tags: python, azure-functions, python-docx

I am Working on **Azure functions** in Azure cognitive search.

My requirement is to retrieve documents that are stored in **azure blob storage** as an input to the **python** azure function and subdividing the document into sections using **python docx** module and store the sections into Azure Table storage.

when I try to pass a path of a blob as an argument of Document, I am getting **Package Not found error**.How to get a path of a blob document in python azure function.

But the code is working fine in my Python IDE locally with docx module.

I am using
Python 3.7.1

VS Code 1.43.2

docx 0.8.10

Azure function 2

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

My code is:

```
import logging
import docx
import azure.functions as func
def main(myblob: func.InputStream,outputtable: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {myblob.name}\n" f"Name: {type(myblob.name)}")
    doc=docx.Document(myblob.name)
```

Comment: Can you show the code? Otherwise it will be hard to help.

Comment: Hi BowmanZhu ,thank you for the response.Could you say how to get the path of the document that is stored in azure blob storage

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Document constructor](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor)

> docx.Document(docx=None)
>
> Return a Document object loaded from docx, where docx can be either a
>   path to a .docx file (a string) or a file-like object. If docx is
>   missing or None, the built-in default document “template” is loaded.

At the same time, by referring to the official documentation: [Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python#usage), you can only access blob data via the parameter typed as InputStream in function.

So, there is no direct path here, what you need to do is to [Opening a ‘file-like’ document](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html#opening-a-file-like-document).

Comment: Hi Jack.When I tried with file like document,I am getting "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputStream" error.Could you say what does it means.

Comment: Just as the message shows, it does not accept stream.  But it accept bytes, so you may read all the blob contents as bytes first